# How to update table row +1 when element is clicked?

Tags: php, mysql, count, row, voting

I am building a voting system for questions. Visitors of the site can vote, once a day or some such, on a question they like the most. **How can I +1 to the `QuestionVotes` row when the button for the specific question is clicked?**

**My code:**

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
    }
    $sql = "SELECT QuestionHeader, QuestionText, QuestionVotes FROM question ORDER BY QuestionVotes DESC LIMIT 3";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<div class=\"col-md-4\"><h2>". $row["QuestionHeader"]. "</h2><p>". $row["QuestionText"]. "</p><p><a class=\"btn btn-success\"> " . $row["QuestionVotes"] . "</a></p></div>";
         }
    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }

    $connection->close();
?>
```

I would guess I have to store the QuestionID somehow and then retrieve it when the button is clicked, but I am clueless as to how? And how do I avoid people voting twice on the same question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you will  need to alter your DB table or create additional tables that links together and have a 1 to many relationship, the question table is the 1 and the table that stores each `user's vote` is the many side.

1. Each question should have a unique ID
2. Loop through the questions from the `Questions` table as you have above. Each row should have a button that when clicked passes the question ID + user ID/(IP Address - if the system is open to non registered users) to the `user's vote` table.

   2a. To increment the count each time a unique user clicks the `vote` button, you will have to `Fetch` to get a `Count`  from the `user's vote` table to see how many times that `Question ID` exists.
3. But, before storing the data in the DB, do a check on the  `user's vote` table to see if that user ID + Question ID is already matched, if so; return a message telling the user that they already voted on that question (Or you can get fancy and do a if check on the page, if there is a match - disable the vote button)

   ```
    $dbname = "DB HERE";
    $servername = "HOST HERE";
    $username = "DB USER HERE";
    $password = "DB PASSWORD HERE";

     // Create connection
     $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                    if(isset($_GET['id']))
               {
                   ///Check to see if user already voted
                   $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM User_Votes where user id = $session_id and question_id = $id");
                   $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

                   if($row_cnt < 1)
                   {
                       ///SQL to insert vote into Users Votes table
                   }else
                   {
                       //Vote already exists
                   }

               }

               // Loop through questions for voting
               $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from questions");
               while($db_questions = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
               {   
                   echo $db_questions->question_title;
                   echo '- <a href="mypage.php?id=$db_questions->question_id">Click to Vote</a>;
               }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the well-described answer! I understand your solution and creating a user table and the relation between the two tables will be easy. Problem is though, that I am very new to PHP and honestly don't quite know how I would go around looping through the questions from the question table, using fetch to get  a count or even checking if User ID and Question ID is already matched, Could you possible specify in deeper detail so that I can hopefully figure it out? Again, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user2304993 -  I will edit my answers with examples. I did not test the code I provided for syntax errors  - there are many ways to skin a cat, so it can be re-written better to be more secured and efficient. But... It gives you the basis of what you need to do. I would advise going to php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and do some reading. –

Comment: Thank you for all your time, I am trying to get through this slow and steady. I am though, confused as to what exactly you get from the 'if(isset($_GET['id']))'? And where the question_id / $id comes from? Also, I have followed your link and am reading up on the things you have mentioned, thanks!

Comment: @user2304993 -   `if(isset($_GET['id']))` is checking to see if the user clicked the vote button, the `id` variable will contain the `question ID` for the question that the user clicked vote on (visible in the browser URL) - and you will create a table called `users_vote` and a column inside there should be `question_id` so when the user clicks vote, you will insert the `id` into the `question_id` column, so onn and so forth.

Comment: Ah, okay, I get that now. There's still one more thing that I am a little unclear on though, where in the progress should I use my original piece of code to generate the html version of the questions and buttons? Cause you build the href while looping through the questions?

Comment: @user2304993 - yes, You can replace my `// Loop through questions for voting` bit, with yours. It does essentially the same thing; Generate html + button for each question.

Comment: Okay, last question, I promise! Where does the $session_id come from? And don't I need to declare it first? Also, thank you loads for your help again!

Comment: @user2304993 - Assuming the voting users are registered, then the `$session_id` would store their `unique ID` from the users table. If you do not have a registration system, (Users are guests) - then you can store their IP address in the `$session_id` variable in order to  identify them uniquely.

Comment: And I would store their IP address with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] right? Again thank you, I think I nearly have my own version working.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest hurdle you will have is identifying unique users. The best way is to force registration and login. That's a discussion for another topic.

Regardless of that your table needs to have 2 other columns.

`QuestionID` MediumINT (15), Unsigned, Primary Index, Auto Increment. This should be the very first column.

`QuestionVoters` Text, NULL. This field will hold a json encoded array of userid's that have voted. `array('123', '38', '27', '15')`

In your `While()` loop check if the user's ID is in the `QuestionVoters` array.

If it exists, then don't give them a voting action. Otherwise build out a form using a button to submit to a processing page.

```
<?php
// Need to assign the user's ID to a variable ($userID) to pass to the form.
$userID = '123'; // this needs to be handled on your end.

// updated sql to include Id and voters
$sql = "SELECT QuestionID, QuestionHeader, QuestionText, QuestionVotes, QuestionVoters FROM question ORDER BY QuestionVotes DESC LIMIT 3";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $voters = json_decode($row['QuestionVoters'], true); // array of userid's that have voted
    IF (in_array($userID, $voters)) {
        // user has voted
        echo "\n
        <div class=\"col-md-4\">
            <h2>". $row["QuestionHeader"]. "</h2>
            <p>". $row["QuestionText"]. "</p>
            <p>" . $row["QuestionVotes"] . "</p>
        </div>";
    }ELSE{
        // user has not voted
        echo "\n
        <div class=\"col-md-4\">
            <form action=\"vote_processing.php\" name=\"voting\" method=\"post\">
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"qid\" value=\"".$row['QuestionID']."\" />
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"userid\" value=\"".$userID."\" />
            <h2>". $row["QuestionHeader"]. "</h2>
            <p>". $row["QuestionText"]. "</p>
            <p><button type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">" . $row["QuestionVotes"] . "</button></p>
            </form>
        </div>";
    }

}
?>
```

**vote_processing.php** (example)

```
<?php
IF (isset($_POST['qid'])) {

    $qid = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST['qid']))); // basic sanitization
    $userid = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST['userid']))); // basic sanitization

    IF ( (is_int($qid)) && (is_int($userid)) ) { // validate that both are integers

        // db connection
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
        mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
        if (!$connection) {
            die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
        }

        // Get voters array
        $sql = "SELECT QuestionVoters FROM question WHERE QuestionID = '".$qid."'";
        $result = $connection->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                IF (!empty($row['QuestionVoters'])) {
                  // decode users array
                  $voters = json_decode($row['QuestionVoters'], true);
                }ELSE{
                  $voters = array(); // create array
                }
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);

            // re-validate the userID "is not" in array
            IF (!in_array($userid, $voters)) { // note the ! [meaning NOT].

                $voters[] = $userid; // add userid to voters array
                $qvoters = json_encode($voters); // encode voters array

                // update vote
                $sql_upd = "UPDATE question SET QuestionVotes = QuestionVotes + 1, QuestionVoters = $qvoters WHERE QuestionID = '".$qid."'";
                $upd_result = $connection->query($sql_upd);

            }

        }

        mysqli_close($connection);

    }

}

// redirct back to previous page
?>
```